# C++ Karatsuba long integer algorithm error

Tags: c++, algorithm

i got this error = `Unhandled exception at 0x7A5B1088 (ucrtbased.dll) in algorthmprokect1.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x006B2FF4). occurred`

i don't know where i have a mistake i am using strings because i need to get integers from file and they has 1000 digits

Update:After Debugging i realized that else statement runs infinite number of times but i still didn't found the solution.

```
string karatsuba(string X,string Y) {
if (X.length()==1 || (X.length()==2 && ((X.substr(0, 1).compare("-") == 0))))
{
    int buf = stoi(X) * stoi(Y);       //multiply if int has single digit
    return to_string (buf);
}
else
{
    string X1 = X.substr(0, (X.length()/2));                      //divide half to X
    string X2 = X.substr((X.length() / 2), X.length());   

    string Y1 = Y.substr(0, (Y.length() / 2));                // divide half to Y
    string Y2 = Y.substr((Y.length() / 2) , Y.length() );



   string U= karatsuba(X1, X2);
   string V = karatsuba(Y1, Y2);
   string W = karatsuba(to_string(stoi(X1) - stoi(X2)), to_string(stoi(Y1) - stoi(Y2)));
   string Z = to_string(stoi(U) + stoi(V) - stoi(W));
   string P = to_string(pow(10, X.length()) * stoi(U) + pow(10, X.length() / 2) * stoi(Z) + stoi(V));
   return P;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you know what it meant by a `Stack overflow` error?  You are recursively calling `karatsuba` over and over again without returning from the function, thus exhausting the stack memory.

Comment: i see but still i couldn't find a solution

Comment: When you write a program, you must have had a plan in mind.  Every line of code, every variable, every function, every path the code can take, you know what should be done.  Thus when an issue occurs and you debug your program, you single-step through your program to see where the program diverges from your plan.  Then you either fix the program so it follows your plan, or realize your plan will not work and make adjustments.  Just saying "I don't know how to fix the error" is not really an excuse.  If you wrote the program *hoping* that things work -- that is the first misstep.

Comment: In the case of recursion, you need to handle the base case first, and guarantee that any of your recursive calls operate on a smaller data size (half, in this case). This one's going to be a debugging problem, so you need to put the effort in. I'm not going to hassle you about [mcve] until after you put the debugging effort in.

Comment: Please revisit any understandable presentation of Karatsuba's multiplication algorithm, starting with how to "split" the factors. Why would `Y` fit in an int when -9 ≤ `X` ≤ 9? Why, in handling `W`, `Z`, `P`, would the parts fit?

Answer (score 0):

This code is not working properly because of the infinite recursion. 
But this is not the main problem of it.

The main problem is: it's a *brilliant example of how not to do*. You are severe underqualified to do such tasks. There is no point in attempts to fix this code, you must simply put it into trash. I would recommend to start with the [GNU MP library](https://gmplib.org). You can learn much from the source code and documentation there how to work with big integers and implement big integer algorithms. You may also try to read [this source](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf).